# Atomically swap an atom that stores an infinite lazy seq

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation

Either I'm exhausted for the day and not able to think properly, or this is not possible, but I wanted to `swap!` an atom that refers to an infinite lazy seq with the `rest` of the seq that is currently in it

My program hangs for obvious reasons because `compare-and-set!` tries to check for previous and new seq equality before swapping. The equality check basically never terminates

Any clue on how to achieve this?

```
(def  beyond-infinity (atom (repeat 1)))
(defn keep-pulling [] (swap! beyond-infinity #(rest %)))
```

**EDIT**

Previously my lazy seq was `range` in which it worked, but on REPL due to realization of the returned seq, my REPL was hung

Anyway, with `repeat` it still fails

Comment: For me it works as well with `repeat` as it does with `range`, although with `range` I can at least check the first element to see that it's doing something --- in any case, I'm not having any problem with it hanging with `repeat` (in the repl I'm doing `(do (keep-pulling) nil)` to avoid the problem you mentioned).

Comment: @jas my bad it was the REPL causing the problem

Answer (score 3):

The issue was because of my REPL trying to realize an infinite sequence.
Also the thing I mentioned about `compare-and-set!` doing a equality check of the seq is wrong. The `compare-and-set!` does a reference equality test and not of the value!